How to use chemmacros to add subscript specifying the first and second acidity/basicity constant?
When using chemmacros to write mathematical equations about the dissociation constants Ka and Kb, the package has a specific command to write pKa1, pKb2 etc.(e.g. \pKa[1]), but there doesn't seem to be any command (such as \Ka[1] or \Kb[2]) for adding the subscript number Ka1 or Kb1.
When trying to solve this using \renewcommand{\Ka}[1]{K_{\textrm{a}#1}} it doesn't work.
This seems like a significant oversight, is there a way to use the built-in chemmacros commands for getting the right output, or alternatively, how to redefine \Ka and \Kb to allow this?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{chemgreek}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\begin{document}

$$
- \log_{10} K_{\textrm{a}1} = \pKa[1]
$$
$$
- \log_{10} \Ka[1] = \pKa[1]
$$
\end{document}

The first equation gives the output that I want and the second has the input that I want to use.

unrelated to you problem, but https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to

latexdef -p chemmacros "pKa code" shows the definition used for \pka:
\pKa code:
\protected\long macro:#1->\chemmacros_p:n {\Ka \IfNoValueF {#1}{{}\c_math_subscript_token {\chemmacros_bold:n {#1}}}}

By analogy, you can redefine the \Ka command, after a backup of its original definition
\NewCommandCopy\oldKa\Ka
\ExplSyntaxOn
\RenewDocumentCommand{\Ka}{ o }
  {
    \oldKa
    \IfNoValueF {#1}
      { {} \c_math_subscript_token { \chemmacros_bold:n {#1} } }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

Example:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{chemgreek}
\usepackage{chemmacros}


\NewCommandCopy\oldKa\Ka
\ExplSyntaxOn
\RenewDocumentCommand{\Ka}{ o }
  {
    \oldKa
    \IfNoValueF {#1}
      { {} \c_math_subscript_token { \chemmacros_bold:n {#1} } }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\[
- \log_{10} \Ka[1] = \pKa[1]
\]


\end{document}



You can additionally redefine \Kb[#] the same way. Thank you, I wasn't accustomed to that syntax.

@PiotrSkubis In fact your code works if you define a command with an optional argument, like \renewcommand{\Ka}[1][]{K_{\textrm{a}#1}}. But it's preferable to reuse the original chemmacros definition. \NewCommandCopy and \NewDocumentCommand are documented in the current  LaTeX user guide).
